# "More" than nowhere locally bounded function

Tags: real-analysis, functions

I describe [here](http://www.mathcounterexamples.net/a-nowhere-locally-bounded-function/) a function $g$ (based on Thomae's function) that is nowhere locally bounded. In particular the image of any interval $(a,b)$ under $g$ is an unbounded segment of the integers $\mathbb{N}$.

[image: A partial plot of $g$]

Is it possible to find a function such that the image of any interval $(a,b)$ would be  the full set of the reals?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you are looking for the [Conway base 13 function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway_base_13_function) which is an example for the more general class of strongly Darboux functions.
These share the property of mapping every open interval of the reals to the whole line.